# Get memberinfo from a type

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-4.0

I'm trying to get memberinfo of a specific type in runtime. 
Using .Net 4.5 was simple with:

MemberInfo mi = t.GetTypeInfo() ;

Where t is of type Type.

But trying to do the same in .Net 4.0 proved to be very hard.

Solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Type` class [inherits `MemberInfo`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/type.cs,42).

You don't need to do anything.